# JS includes from array to momentjs current date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am wanting `true` or `false` return when using `includes` to see if the current month using `moment().format('MMMM')` is also in an `array`.

```
const splitMonths = ['April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September'];
const currentDate = moment().format('MMMM');
const seasonData = currentDate.includes(splitMonths);
console.log(seasonData);
```

The above returns `false` and I cannot understand why.

If I change `splitMonths` to `splitMonths = ['May'];` it will return `true`.

If I run `console.log(currentDate)` it returns `May`.

Why isn't this returning `true`?

Comment: You need to use `splitMonths.includes(currentDate);`. You are checking array existence within the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking array existence within the string `currentDate.includes(splitMonths);`. Instead it should be `splitMonths.includes(currentDate);`

```js
const splitMonths = ['April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September'];
const month = "May";
const seasonData = splitMonths.includes(month);
console.log(seasonData);
```